# "Detached entity passed to persist:" when entity is not detached

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm getting an error saying that my entity is detached when I try to persist it. When debugging I can see that the objects I try to save have an ID. I am guessing that this might be related to my annotations in JPA but I cannot figure out what is the cause of this problem.

Class with method that causes error(the last line of doStuff() is responsible):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ConcreteMyController implements MyController {

    private final CategoryService categoryService;
    private final OrmFactory ormFactory;
    private final SongService songService;
    private final CategoryForSongService categoryForSongService;

    @Autowired
    public ConcreteMyController(CategoryService categoryService, OrmFactory ormFactory, SongService songService, CategoryForSongService categoryForSongService) {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.ormFactory = ormFactory;
        this.songService = songService;
        this.categoryForSongService = categoryForSongService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        String title = "BestSongInTheWorld";
        String popCategoryName = "pop";
        String rockCategoryName = "rock";
        String jazzCategoryName = "jazz";

        Song song = this.ormFactory.createSong(title, "3:14");
        this.songService.save(song);
        Set<Category> categories = Sets.newHashSet(new Category(popCategoryName), new Category(rockCategoryName), new Category(jazzCategoryName));
        this.categoryService.save(categories);

        Song retrievedSong = songService.get(title);
        Set<Category> retrievedCategories = categoryService.get(Sets.newHashSet(popCategoryName, rockCategoryName));

        CategoryForSong categoryForSong = new CategoryForSong(retrievedSong.getTitle(), retrievedCategories);
        this.categoryForSongService.save(categoryForSong);

    }
}
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Song implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "duration")
    private String duration;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class CategoryForSong implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Category> categories;
    @Column(name = "songTitle")
    private String songTitle;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

Getters, setters, equals etc. has been omitted. The reason that CategoryForSong contains a string with a songTitle instead of an actual Song is just me trying to isolate the problem. That did not seem to help.

My services are not very interesting, so I will add the one for Song here just to show the structure:

```
@Service
public class ConcreteSongService implements SongService {

    @Autowired
    private SongRepository songRepository;


    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(Song song) {
        songRepository.save(song);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Song get(String title) {
        return songRepository.getByTitle(Sets.newHashSet(title)).stream().findFirst().get();

    }
}
```

And the repository is as simple as this:

```
public interface SongRepository extends CrudRepository<Song, Long> {

    Set<Song> getByTitle(Set<String> titles);
}
```

The exception looks like this:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: proofofconcept.springmvc.model.orm.Category
```

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is this because the list of categories is detached? When you save the categories, the service method has a Transactional annotation, so it will open a transaction, save the categories, then close the transaction + hibernate session. Try adding the Transactional annotation to your controller method and see if it works then...

Comment: i.e. to `doStuff()`

Comment: Adding transactional to the controller causes it to stop working. It seems to not be possible(without some kind of workaraound) in Spring due to their proxy setup. Should this logic be moved one layer down and be put transactional there?

Comment: That ought to do it...

Comment: Can you attach a bit detailed consol. You also can try with using merge() instead of save to resolve this issue.